# System.TypeLoadException (when accessing .Net standard 4.6.1 Visual basic class library from ASP.Net core 2.0 Web API)

Tags: c#, vb.net, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a .Net standard 4.6.1 Visual basic class library and a ASP.Net core 2.0 Web API project created using C#. I'm trying to pass an object array from the web API to a function in Visual basic class library and get response object. 
I'm getting and error, System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Is ASP.Net Core 2.0 not compatible in consuming a .Net Standard Visual basic Class library ? Can anyone please help me out on this ?

Comment: It's totally possible to have .NET standard visual basic library. However, Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information is not supported in .net standard. What I think has happened, is your .net standard library is referencing a .net framework package and that is why it all seems to compile. If you visit this site, https://icanhasdot.net/ ,  you will see what dependencies in your vs library project are supported in .net core

Comment: There is no such thing as .NET Standard 4.6.1. Is it .NET Framework 4.6.1, or is it .NET Standard 2.x or lower?